# Rename double-date to dual-date

Tags: discussion, retagging, tags

Can we rename the [double-date](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-date) tag to [dual-date](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-date)? As I jokingly mentioned in a previous response, a "double date" is a social event.

This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_dating) explains the rationale behind this terminology.

Comment: Are we really going to get confused about this, given the overarching context of this site? I'd rather use the terminology that is most often used by historians, whatever that is.

Comment: I use the "dual" term myself, and always have, but I take your point. It's a shame the tags don't have alternative names. I don't like the US-spelling, for instance, of 'artifact', although I tolerate it because most people on this site are from the US

Comment: Once somebody has enough rep, I think they can create tag synonyms, so mis-tagging is automatically corrected as per http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms, but first we need to decide which is the definitive version...

Comment: Interesting. I'm not so familiar with the term as "dual." I see that Wikipedia has it that way, but suspect that might have something to do with the conflicting article (title) about social "group dating."

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen the term "double date" used, never "dual date".

The Wikipedia article you refer states in Reference 1 that the reason it used the term "dual date" is because:

> 1. In order to limit confusion with Dating (activity), the term dual dating is used as the title of this article.

That's no reason to assign something an incorrect name.

Comment: On the other hand, I have never used "double date", or "double year" (which is also common but technically incorrect)